# Can't create a instance of a abstracted class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance

I have a problem with this code when I tried to create an instance of this class, an error appears to be

```
not allowed to use the abstracted class "SavingAccount"
```

I don't know what can I do. I followed the steps given by edx Microsoft Intermediate C++.

**BankAccount.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class BankAccount
{
protected: 
    double balance;
public:

BankAccount(double initialBanlance);
virtual ~BankAccount();

double getBalance() const;

virtual void deposit(double amount);
virtual void withdraw(double amount);

virtual std::string getTermAndConditions() = 0;
virtual double getGuaranteeLimit() = 0;};
```

**BankAccount.cpp**

```
#include "BankAccount.h"

BankAccount::BankAccount(double initialBanlance)
:balance(initialBanlance)
{}

BankAccount::~BankAccount()
{}

double BankAccount::getBalance() const
{return balance;}

void BankAccount::deposit(double amount)
{
balance += amount;
}

void BankAccount::withdraw(double amount)
{balance -= amount;}
```

---

**Freezable.h**

```
#pragma once
//Pure virtual class ,representing the "freeable" capability
class Freezable {
public:
virtual void freeze()=0;
virtual void unfreeze()=0;
};
```

---

**Loggable.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
//Pure virtual class, representing the "loggable"'
class loggable{
public:
virtual void log(const std::string& message)const = 0;};
```

---

**SavingAccount.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "BankAccount.h"
#include "Freezable.h"
#include "Loggable.h"

#include <list>
class SavingAccount :public BankAccount, public Freezable, public loggable
{
private:
    double interestRate;
    bool frozen;
public:
    SavingAccount(double initialBalance, double interestRate = 0.0);
    virtual ~SavingAccount();

    void earnInterest();

    virtual void deposit(double amount);
    virtual void withdraw(double amount);

    //implement  pure virtual function from BankAccount class.
    virtual std::string getTermAndConditions();
    virtual double getGuarranteeLimit();

    //Implement pure virtual from Freezable
    virtual void freeze();
    virtual void unfreeze();

    //Implement pure virtual from Loggable class
    virtual void log(const std::string & message)const;
};
```

**SavingAccount.cpp**

```
 #include "SavingAccount.h"
 #include <iostream>

 SavingAccount::SavingAccount(double initialBalance, double interestRate)
    :BankAccount(initialBalance), interestRate(interestRate), frozen(false)
{}    
SavingAccount::~SavingAccount() {}    
void SavingAccount::earnInterest()
{
    if (!frozen) {
        double interest = balance * (interestRate / 100);
        deposit(interest);
    }
}    
void SavingAccount::deposit(double amount) {
    if (!frozen) {
        BankAccount::deposit(amount);
        log("Deposit:" + std::to_string(amount));
    }
}    
void SavingAccount::withdraw(double amount) {
    if (!frozen && amount <= balance) {
        BankAccount::withdraw(amount);
        log("withdrwal:" + std::to_string(amount));
    }
}    
std::string SavingAccount::getTermAndConditions() {
    return "This is a savings account, You cannot go overdrawn.You  earn interest.";
}    
double SavingAccount::getGuarranteeLimit() {    return 1000000; }

void SavingAccount::freeze() {  frozen = true; }

void SavingAccount::unfreeze() {    frozen = false; }

void SavingAccount::log(const std::string & message) const 
{   std::cout << message << std::endl; }
```

Comment: You really need to extract a [mcve] before posting here. As it stands, it is off-topic due to its lack. As a new user, also make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo. The base class `BankAccount` is a *pure abstract class*, which has a virtual member function called

```
virtual double getGuaranteeLimit() = 0;
                    ^^
```

and in your `SavingAccount` class(which is derived) you have implemented

```
virtual double getGuarranteeLimit();
                     ^^
```

which is **not same as base class**. Hence, you never *override* the function in your derived class.
 That is why you need to practice with *[override specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)* which will produce a compiler error if no matching function is found in base class.

See, for example, compiling with [Clag 7.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/49I8yoq7hg3XAsDf) clearly gives a compiler error:

```
prog.cc:76:17: error: 'getGuarranteeLimit' marked 'override' but does not override any member functions
        virtual double getGuarranteeLimit()override;
```